# remove dot from decimal in double and keeping decimal values in the integer

Tags: ios, swift

for example let's just say I have a:

```
var num: double = 123.123
```

How can I get an Integer of : 123123

Comment: And what result would you expect for `num = 1231.23` or `num = 4.7`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let num: Double = 123.123
print(Int(String(num).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "")))
```

Comment: Try this with `let num = 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
formatter.decimalSeparator = ""

let a = 123.132
let b = formatter.stringFromNumber(a)
```

this returns a String, to cast to Int you can:

```
if let b = formatter.stringFromNumber(a) {
    let c = Int(b)
}
```

Comment: The only correct answer. Problem with number of symbols unsolvable anyway in this question: 123.00000001 and 123 input numbers breaks OP idea

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into the string and remove "." and convert it to Integer. Simple

```
let num: Double = 123.123
var stringNum : String = String(num)
stringNum = stringNum.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "")
let finalInt = Int(stringNum)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Try this with `let num = 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3` :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
let value = 100.155
print(value) // 100.155 
let str = String(value) 
print(str) //100.155

let newValue = Int(str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "")) 
print(newValue)// Optional(100155) . unwrap it 
print(newvalue!) // 100155
```

Comment: Try this with `let value = 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3` :)